# Laravel 8 eager loading, how to access subquery fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is working:

```
$clients = Client::with([
    'contacts' => function ($query) {
        $query
            ->select('client_id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
            ->where('contact_type_id', '=', 1);
    }])
    ->orderBy('client_name')
    ->get(['id', 'client_name', 'city', 'state']);

dd($clients);
```

However, I'm unsure of how to access first_name and last_name on the subquery. They're showing up in the "relations" object in the dump, but in my mind I'm envisioning a dataset that I would access like,

$client->first_name, etc.

When I try to add the fields to the get() method at the end, it doesn't recognize them, so I'm doing something wrong, or I need to access the subquery fields differently.

Comment: You would access them via `$client->contacts->first()->first_name` if a client might have many contacts or `$client->contacts->first_name` if the client only has one contact (though in that case naming the relationship `contacts` is misleading)

Comment: ok, yeah they have multiple contacts, but in this particular query I'm limiting it to just one of the contacts based on type.

Answer (score 0):

When you are eager loading the relationships, you are just preloading them.

If your relationship is defined as `hasMany` (which seems to be the case here, a `Client hasMany Contact`), then you'll always get a collection from eager loading.

If you defined another relationship in your model in order to get only one result, for instance:

```php
public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->where('contact_type_id', 1)->latest('id');
}
```

Your new relationship `contact` would return only one result:

```php
$clients = Client::with('contact')
    ->orderBy('client_name')
    ->get(['id', 'client_name', 'city', 'state']);

foreach($clients as $client){
    dd($client->contact->first_name);
}

// each Client of $clients would have a ->contact relationship
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add field id to select() method in subquery and field contact_id to get() method

```
$clients = Client::with(['contacts' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'client_id', 'first_name', 'last_name')->where('contact_type_id', '=', 1);
}])
->orderBy('client_name')
->get(['id', 'client_name', 'city', 'state', 'contact_id']);
foreach ($clients as $key => $client) {
    dd($client->contacts->first_name);
    // Or
    dd($client->contacts()->first()->first_name);
}
```